# 'Pandoc.exe out of memory' with leaflet publishing - R studio

Tags: r, leaflet, pandoc

I am trying to export an html and publish my interactive map, created with leaflet in R studio..

I get a variety of error messages which seem to revolve around a memory issue. The error I get is when trying to use savewidget from htmlwidgets package.

However, checking my CPU it is nowhere near being overloaded. I have 16GB of ram memory and plenty of that is free. R studio itself is consuming only around 1 GB.

I have tried using a little program called Large Address Aware to allow .exe files to use more than 2 GB but it hasn't made a difference.

Also note that when using other methods to publish such as the publish button or export as web page I get different errors such as 'Pandoc Document conversion failed with error 1'.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried setting `selfcontained = FALSE` in `saveWidget`?

Comment: Wowza! Didn't expect it to but that actually did it! Thanks! Only slightly strange thing is that when I mouse over the labels they all pop up and stay there rather than disappearing when you move off them. Probably a different issue altogether though..

Comment: quite likely a different issue

Comment: 5* solution, @TimSalabim - surprising to me how hard this was to find, I was trying to install editbin etc but knew this was weird on my 64GB machine, and finally happened on this thread... maybe this use case is unusual because leaflet loses it's lovely interactivity when put into png?  anyway, thanks!